# Dictionary of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

From another function, I have tuples like this `('falseName', 'realName', positionOfMistake)`, eg. `('Milter', 'Miller', 4)`.
I need to write a function that make a dictionary like this:

```
D={realName:{falseName:[positionOfMistake], falseName:[positionOfMistake]...}, 
   realName:{falseName:[positionOfMistake]...}...}
```

The function has to take a dictionary and a tuple like above, as arguments.

I was thinking something like this for a start:

```
def addToNameDictionary(d, tup):
    dictionary={}
    tup=previousFunction(string)
    for element in tup:
        if not dictionary.has_key(element[1]):
            dictionary.append(element[1])
    elif:
        if ...
```

But it is not working and I am kind of stucked here.

Comment: you're indentation is wrong. and what exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: The 'tup' in the parameter is being blown away by the 'tup=previ..' line. The code looks like you're not holding the big picture in your head. I reckon stop, step away from the computer, take a deep breath, go for a walk, sit down, close your eyes, and write the code down with pencil and paper.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it is only to add a new tuple and you are sure that there are no collisions in the inner dictionary, you can do this:

```
def addNameToDictionary(d, tup):
    if tup[0] not in d:
        d[tup[0]] = {}
    d[tup[0]][tup[1]] = [tup[2]]
```

Comment: The has_key test is better written `if tup[0] not in d:`

Comment: `has_key()` is deprecated and has been removed from Python 3.

Comment: This is really useful code.  I was working on a nested dictionary of data extracted from a file and this made a really clean replacement for a failed function I was putting together (after some slight modifications that were specific to my particular use case).  Thanks for this post!

Answer (score 12):

Using `collections.defaultdict` is a big time-saver when you're building dicts and don't know beforehand which keys you're going to have.

Here it's used twice: for the resulting dict, and for each of the values in the dict.

```
import collections

def aggregate_names(errors):
    result = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))
    for real_name, false_name, location in errors:
        result[real_name][false_name].append(location)
    return result
```

Combining this with your code:

```
dictionary = aggregate_names(previousFunction(string))
```

Or to test:

```
EXAMPLES = [
    ('Fred', 'Frad', 123),
    ('Jim', 'Jam', 100),
    ('Fred', 'Frod', 200),
    ('Fred', 'Frad', 300)]
print aggregate_names(EXAMPLES)
```

Answer (score 8):

dictionary's setdefault is a good way to update an existing dict entry if it's there, or create a new one if it's not all in one go:

Looping style:

```
# This is our sample data
data = [("Milter", "Miller", 4), ("Milter", "Miler", 4), ("Milter", "Malter", 2)]

# dictionary we want for the result
dictionary = {}

# loop that makes it work
for realName, falseName, position in data:
    dictionary.setdefault(realName, {})[falseName] = position
```

dictionary now equals:

```
{'Milter': {'Malter': 2, 'Miler': 4, 'Miller': 4}}
```