# need a dictionary from another function

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary from another function, how can I pass the dictionary within a new function?
Eg.

From another function, I have tuples like this `('falseName', 'realName', positionOfMistake)`, eg. `('Milter', 'Miller', 4)`. I have a function that make a dictionary like this:

```
D={realName:{falseName:[positionOfMistake], falseName:[positionOfMistake]...},  
   realName:{falseName:[positionOfMistake]...}...} 

def addNameToDictionary(d, tup): 
    if not d.has_key(tup[0]): 
        d[tup[0]] = {} 
    d[tup[0]][tup[1]] = [tup[2]]
```

Now I need to write a function that takes a list of falseName's and return:

```
realName:
    falseName
    falseName
realName:...
```

My problem is how to call the dictionary from the function addNameToDictionary, to a new function?

I have tried the following:

```
def Names(nameList):
    D=addNameToDictionary(d, tup)
    print D
```

But I get:

```
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined
```

Anyone?

Comment: Why don't you pass the dict to the new function, like you do in *addNameToDictionary*?

Comment: what do you mean by "call the dictionary" and why don't you just pass the `dict` as an argument to the new function?

Comment: well, *d* isn't anywhere in your code. All you have is (capital) *D*. What's more you don't return anything from *addNameToDictionary*.

Comment: I have d as an argument in addNameToDictionary?

Comment: You are trying to pass *d* to *addNameToDictionary* which is not defined. What's defined is capital *D*.

Comment: Here is a list of tutorials. I recommend you pick one and work through it: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers.

Comment: It's not like I havn't tried anywhere else. I am asking here because I cannot figure out how to fix it. Again, i CANNOT take other arguments to the new function than nameList. I understand d!=D, but it still isn't working!

Comment: You've already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550912/python-dictionary-of-dictionaries/8550946#8550946 and got a lot of help. Perhaps you need to read some programming tutorials before asking more questions.

Comment: @LinusSvendsson: Why CAN YOU NOT add further arguments to your function?

Answer (score 0):

```
def your_new_function(d, falseNames):
    # ... get data from d
    return {realname:(falseName1, falseName2)}
```

Comment: but the function should take a list of falseName's, not falseNames and dict.

Comment: Well, *D* is a global variable in your code right? You can access it inside your new function.

Comment: Hmm.. I still don't know how to do it?!